# strcmp of array of strings and string

Tags: c, strcmp

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with strcmp? I don't understand why I am getting a segmentation fault when comparing array of strings and string.

I figured out my problem just not sure how to go about fixing it. I will eventually be putting nam into strings based on my hash function. Before I do this though I want to check if my string already exists in my string array. If it does not exist I want to put it into the array. If it does exist I don't want to put it into my array. So I am guessing when I use strcmp on a non existent value I get null. Is there a good way to handle this?

```
char *strings[100];
char nam[100];
int g = 0;
while (fscanf(pFile, "%s %d",  nam, &val) !=EOF)
{

    strings[k] = nam;
    printf(" string is %s .\n", strings[k]);
    k++;
    i = 0;
    g = (int) strcmp (strings[0], nam);
    printf("g is %d \n", g);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp (strings[i], nam) == 0)
        {
            printf(" strings[i] is equal");
        }
    }
    printf(" Bust out");
}
```

It also didn't like this. I figured I was getting a null on the non existent values so this would work.

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(strcmp (strings[i], nam) == '\0')
    {
        printf(" strings[i] is equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: You read each new value into `nam`, but all the previously set pointers point to `nam` too, so the strings are all the same.  If you want the different values all available at once, you'll have to allocate separate storage for each string.

Comment: Doesn't this do that? `char *strings[100]`

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand how You are getting an error. This is How i tested it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *strings[100];
    char nam[100];

    strcpy(nam, "ansh");
    strings[1] = nam;

    printf("\n%s", nam);
    printf("\n%s", strings[1]);

    int k = strcmp(nam, strings[1]);
    printf("\n%d\n", k);
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT-

```
ansh
ansh
0
```

Comment: your code just run for one time and it will not cover old value,so it will be right.

Comment: could You post Your so that I can have a Look. I dont know how You went about the values of variable.

Comment: you can see upper answer.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to figure out my problem just not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped), If doesn't like my if statement in my for loop. I will randomly be putting values into strings based on my hash function so I want to check through my whole array if nam already exists in my string array. I don't know how to go about fixing this.

Comment: Check `strstr()` and `strtok()` if u want to check in nam exsists in the string

Answer (score 0):

you should malloc for nam or strings[k] to keep value,in the while loop ,when nam changes ,strings[k] will point somewhere unknown.

```
char *strings[100];
char nam[100];
int g = 0;
while (fscanf(pFile, "%s %d",  nam, &val) !=EOF)
{
    char *tmp = malloc( strlen(nam) + 1 );
    strcpy( tmp , nam );
    strings[k] = tmp;

    printf(" string is %s .\n", strings[k]);
    k++;
    g = strcmp (strings[i], nam);
    printf("g is %d \n", g);
}
```

Comment: I added my for loop so you can understand my problem better.